# Error inflating class on BottomNavigationView and style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I'm getting two errors, which probably relate to the BottomNavigationView in my DashBoardActivity. This only occurs for some users and not all.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adit.bangkit.plagroid/com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activities.DashboardActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_dashboard: Binary XML file line #8 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_dashboard: Binary XML file line #8 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.databinding.ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(ActivityDashboardBinding.java:49)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.databinding.ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(ActivityDashboardBinding.java:43)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activities.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.kt:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:247)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:212)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:147)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:114)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.<init>(NavigationBarView.java:145)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:108)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:103)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:98)
```

here is my dashboard activity:

```
class DashboardActivity : BaseActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityDashboardBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // Update the background color of the action bar as per our design requirement.
    supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this@DashboardActivity,
            R.drawable.app_gradient_color_background
        )
    )
    // END

    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_dashboard,
            R.id.navigation_orders,
            R.id.navigation_sold_products
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    doubleBackToExit()
}
}
```

Here is my BottomNavigationView details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Line 8 in the error points to <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView. This is my layout for bottomNavigationView.

My application theme inherits from "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge".

Firstly, my bottom_nav_colours was in the drawable folder and it crashes for some users. Tried to duplicate it also in the existing drawable-any-dpi-v24 folder and it still crashes.

Not sure what to do here. I think the issue is to do with <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView in the activity_dashboard.

i've tried to update di library and re-checking all resources that used in layout but can't work. hope with this question it can be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue too..
it seems like to be a bug..
Just change in xml:

```
<fragment
       .....
```

To

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
       .....
```

and in code instead of:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

to

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```